# Excel VBA changing decimal from point to comma

Tags: excel, vba, decimal

When Im working with decimals in arrays, VBA is changing the decimal point into comma:

[image]

And, since the comma is already the separator, VBA is separating the decimals into two integer numbers(e.g. 0,01 into 0 and 01, and 0.21 into 0 and 21

Im using the split/join technique since I need to merge several arrays depending on an index.

Is there any way to stop VBA converting decimals from point to comma?

Thanks

Comment: As a note, your question is ok, the problem is that you posted the code as image whereas should be as code (that we can copy/paste), note that for the next time so you don't get downvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Str` and text values, as `Join` always returns text:

```
Join(Array(Str(Val / 100), "0.021", "2")
```